# Convertir de números a palabras

Tags: c#, sql

Hay algún algoritmo o alguna función que me convierta ya sea desde la SQL o desde C# de números decimales a letras, ejemplo: 150.50 = "ciento cincuenta con cincuenta centavos."

Comment: Gracias @sstan si he estado buscando alguna api que pueda descargar pero solo veo que hay una en indio y otra que es en inglés, en ultima instancia usar la del inglés.

Comment: @sstan en mi auto respuesta deje como se resuelve esto.

Comment: Hola Cris. Gracias por compartir la autorespuesta sin embargo la pregunta tiene que tener validez en el sitio. Tal y como está redactada pides sugerencias o ideas de algoritmos lo que es *basado en opiniones* además que tienes que mostrar lo intentado y dodne falló . Mira [ask] para mejorarla aun siendo  pregunta+respuesta. un saludo

Comment: Esta es una pregunta autorespondida

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En realidad sí que existe una librería para hacer esto que soporta múltiples idiomas: [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer)

Existen múltiples paquetes Nuget que te permiten añadir a tu proyecto la librería para todos los idiomas o sólo para algunos específicos. Por ejemplo, si únicamente te interesa el idioma español deberías añadir el paquete Nuget Humanizer.Core.es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para realizar la conversión del número a palabras simplemente deberías utilizar el método de extensión `ToWords`.
Aquí tienes una aplicación de consola de ejemplo de cómo usarlo:

```
using System;
using Humanizer;

namespace ConsoleApp_C
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Introduzca número:");           
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Int32.TryParse(input, out var number)
                    ? $"{number.ToWords()}"
                    : $"No se reconoce el número {input}");
                Console.WriteLine("Introduzca número:");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias también es de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Hola, en la comunidad no es bien visto responder preguntas que no han demostrado un minimo de investogacion y desarrollo.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover ¿En serio te estás dedicando a corregir a usuarios que han respondido a consultas hace 7 años? :o

Comment: no me habia percatado de la fecha -.-

Answer (score 2):

estuvie buscando en otros sitios y hay un pequeño metodo que sirve para esto, ojalá le sirva a alguien en algún momento:

```
    public string enletras(string num)
    {
        string res, dec = "";
        Int64 entero;
        int decimales;
        double nro;

        try

        {
            nro = Convert.ToDouble(num);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }

        entero = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Truncate(nro));
        decimales = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((nro - entero) * 100, 2));
        if (decimales > 0)
        {
            dec = " CON " + decimales.ToString() + "/100";
        }

        res = toText(Convert.ToDouble(entero)) + dec;
        return res;
    }

 private string toText(double value)
    {
        string Num2Text = "";
        value = Math.Truncate(value);
        if (value == 0) Num2Text = "CERO";
        else if (value == 1) Num2Text = "UNO";
        else if (value == 2) Num2Text = "DOS";
        else if (value == 3) Num2Text = "TRES";
        else if (value == 4) Num2Text = "CUATRO";
        else if (value == 5) Num2Text = "CINCO";
        else if (value == 6) Num2Text = "SEIS";
        else if (value == 7) Num2Text = "SIETE";
        else if (value == 8) Num2Text = "OCHO";
        else if (value == 9) Num2Text = "NUEVE";
        else if (value == 10) Num2Text = "DIEZ";
        else if (value == 11) Num2Text = "ONCE";
        else if (value == 12) Num2Text = "DOCE";
        else if (value == 13) Num2Text = "TRECE";
        else if (value == 14) Num2Text = "CATORCE";
        else if (value == 15) Num2Text = "QUINCE";
        else if (value < 20) Num2Text = "DIECI" + toText(value - 10);
        else if (value == 20) Num2Text = "VEINTE";
        else if (value < 30) Num2Text = "VEINTI" + toText(value - 20);
        else if (value == 30) Num2Text = "TREINTA";
        else if (value == 40) Num2Text = "CUARENTA";
        else if (value == 50) Num2Text = "CINCUENTA";
        else if (value == 60) Num2Text = "SESENTA";
        else if (value == 70) Num2Text = "SETENTA";
        else if (value == 80) Num2Text = "OCHENTA";
        else if (value == 90) Num2Text = "NOVENTA";
        else if (value < 100) Num2Text = toText(Math.Truncate(value / 10) * 10) + " Y " + toText(value % 10);
        else if (value == 100) Num2Text = "CIEN";
        else if (value < 200) Num2Text = "CIENTO " + toText(value - 100);
        else if ((value == 200) || (value == 300) || (value == 400) || (value == 600) || (value == 800)) Num2Text = toText(Math.Truncate(value / 100)) + "CIENTOS";
        else if (value == 500) Num2Text = "QUINIENTOS";
        else if (value == 700) Num2Text = "SETECIENTOS";
        else if (value == 900) Num2Text = "NOVECIENTOS";
        else if (value < 1000) Num2Text = toText(Math.Truncate(value / 100) * 100) + " " + toText(value % 100);
        else if (value == 1000) Num2Text = "MIL";
        else if (value < 2000) Num2Text = "MIL " + toText(value % 1000);
        else if (value < 1000000)
        {
            Num2Text = toText(Math.Truncate(value / 1000)) + " MIL";
            if ((value % 1000) > 0) Num2Text = Num2Text + " " + toText(value % 1000);
        }

        else if (value == 1000000) Num2Text = "UN MILLON";
        else if (value < 2000000) Num2Text = "UN MILLON " + toText(value % 1000000);
        else if (value < 1000000000000)
        {
            Num2Text = toText(Math.Truncate(value / 1000000)) + " MILLONES ";
            if ((value - Math.Truncate(value / 1000000) * 1000000) > 0) Num2Text = Num2Text + " " + toText(value - Math.Truncate(value / 1000000) * 1000000);
        }

        else if (value == 1000000000000) Num2Text = "UN BILLON";
        else if (value < 2000000000000) Num2Text = "UN BILLON " + toText(value - Math.Truncate(value / 1000000000000) * 1000000000000);

        else
        {
            Num2Text = toText(Math.Truncate(value / 1000000000000)) + " BILLONES";
            if ((value - Math.Truncate(value / 1000000000000) * 1000000000000) > 0) Num2Text = Num2Text + " " + toText(value - Math.Truncate(value / 1000000000000) * 1000000000000);
        }
        return Num2Text;

    }
```

Comment: +1 En este momento me sirvió a mi, en mi caso le hice algunas modificaciones, como usar un diccionario para almacenar los string con los números que son únicos y evitar usar tantos `if(...) else {...}`.

Comment: Hola, en la comunidad no es bien visto responder preguntas que no han demostrado un minimo de investogacion y desarrollo.